# debootstrap excluding systemd packages

Tags: systemd, debian, debootstrap, sysv

I am debootstrap'ing an Ubuntu to exclude `systemd` and  `systemd-sysv` packages using `--exclude` parameter however upon checking the packages are still occuring. Did I missed more parameters as I am expecting it should no longer be included?

```
root@langaw:~# debootstrap --arch=armhf --exclude=systemd,systemd-sysv --foreign xenial /mnt/root/debootstrap_test4
I: Retrieving InRelease
I: Checking Release signature
I: Valid Release signature (key id 790BC7277767219C42C86F933B4FE6ACC0B21F32)
I: Validating Packages
I: Resolving dependencies of required packages...
I: Resolving dependencies of base packages...
I: Checking component main on http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports...
I: Validating adduser 3.113+nmu3ubuntu4
I: Validating apt 1.2.10ubuntu1
I: Validating apt-utils 1.2.10ubuntu1
I: Validating base-files 9.4ubuntu4
I: Validating base-passwd 3.5.39
I: Validating bash 4.3-14ubuntu1
I: Validating bsdutils 1:2.27.1-6ubuntu3
I: Validating busybox-initramfs 1:1.22.0-15ubuntu1
I: Validating bzip2 1.0.6-8
I: Validating console-setup 1.108ubuntu15
I: Validating console-setup-linux 1.108ubuntu15
I: Validating coreutils 8.25-2ubuntu2
I: Validating cpio 2.11+dfsg-5ubuntu1
I: Validating cron 3.0pl1-128ubuntu2
I: Validating dash 0.5.8-2.1ubuntu2
I: Validating debconf 1.5.58ubuntu1
I: Validating debconf-i18n 1.5.58ubuntu1
I: Validating debianutils 4.7
I: Validating dh-python 2.20151103ubuntu1
I: Validating diffutils 1:3.3-3
I: Validating distro-info-data 0.28
I: Validating dpkg 1.18.4ubuntu1
I: Validating e2fslibs 1.42.13-1ubuntu1
I: Validating e2fsprogs 1.42.13-1ubuntu1
I: Validating eject 2.1.5+deb1+cvs20081104-13.1
I: Validating file 1:5.25-2ubuntu1
I: Validating findutils 4.6.0+git+20160126-2
I: Validating gcc-5-base 5.3.1-14ubuntu2
I: Validating gcc-6-base 6.0.1-0ubuntu1
I: Validating gnupg 1.4.20-1ubuntu3
I: Validating gpgv 1.4.20-1ubuntu3
I: Validating grep 2.24-1
I: Validating gzip 1.6-4ubuntu1
I: Validating hostname 3.16ubuntu2
I: Validating ifupdown 0.8.10ubuntu1
I: Validating init 1.29ubuntu1
I: Validating init-system-helpers 1.29ubuntu1
I: Validating initramfs-tools 0.122ubuntu8
I: Validating initramfs-tools-bin 0.122ubuntu8
I: Validating initramfs-tools-core 0.122ubuntu8
I: Validating initscripts 2.88dsf-59.3ubuntu2
I: Validating insserv 1.14.0-5ubuntu3
I: Validating iproute2 4.3.0-1ubuntu3
I: Validating iputils-ping 3:20121221-5ubuntu2
I: Validating isc-dhcp-client 4.3.3-5ubuntu12
I: Validating isc-dhcp-common 4.3.3-5ubuntu12
I: Validating kbd 1.15.5-1ubuntu4
I: Validating keyboard-configuration 1.108ubuntu15
I: Retrieving klibc-utils 2.0.4-8ubuntu1
I: Validating klibc-utils 2.0.4-8ubuntu1
I: Validating kmod 22-1ubuntu4
I: Validating less 481-2.1
I: Validating libacl1 2.2.52-3
I: Validating libapparmor1 2.10.95-0ubuntu2
I: Validating libapt-inst2.0 1.2.10ubuntu1
I: Validating libapt-pkg5.0 1.2.10ubuntu1
I: Validating libatm1 1:2.5.1-1.5
I: Validating libattr1 1:2.4.47-2
I: Validating libaudit-common 1:2.4.5-1ubuntu2
I: Validating libaudit1 1:2.4.5-1ubuntu2
I: Validating libblkid1 2.27.1-6ubuntu3
I: Validating libbsd0 0.8.2-1
I: Validating libbz2-1.0 1.0.6-8
I: Validating libc-bin 2.23-0ubuntu3
I: Validating libc6 2.23-0ubuntu3
I: Validating libcap2 1:2.24-12
I: Validating libcap2-bin 1:2.24-12
I: Validating libcomerr2 1.42.13-1ubuntu1
I: Validating libcryptsetup4 2:1.6.6-5ubuntu2
I: Validating libdb5.3 5.3.28-11
I: Validating libdebconfclient0 0.198ubuntu1
I: Validating libdevmapper1.02.1 2:1.02.110-1ubuntu10
I: Validating libdns-export162 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8
I: Validating libestr0 0.1.10-1
I: Validating libexpat1 2.1.0-7
I: Validating libfdisk1 2.27.1-6ubuntu3
I: Validating libffi6 3.2.1-4
I: Validating libfribidi0 0.19.7-1
I: Validating libgcc1 1:6.0.1-0ubuntu1
I: Validating libgcrypt20 1.6.5-2
I: Validating libgmp10 2:6.1.0+dfsg-2
I: Validating libgnutls-openssl27 3.4.10-4ubuntu1
I: Validating libgnutls30 3.4.10-4ubuntu1
I: Validating libgpg-error0 1.21-2ubuntu1
I: Validating libhogweed4 3.2-1
I: Validating libidn11 1.32-3ubuntu1
I: Validating libisc-export160 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8
I: Validating libjson-c2 0.11-4ubuntu2
I: Validating libklibc 2.0.4-8ubuntu1
I: Validating libkmod2 22-1ubuntu4
I: Validating liblocale-gettext-perl 1.07-1build1
I: Validating liblz4-1 0.0~r131-2ubuntu2
I: Validating liblzma5 5.1.1alpha+20120614-2ubuntu2
I: Validating libmagic1 1:5.25-2ubuntu1
I: Validating libmnl0 1.0.3-5
I: Validating libmount1 2.27.1-6ubuntu3
I: Validating libmpdec2 2.4.2-1
I: Validating libncurses5 6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1
I: Validating libncursesw5 6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1
I: Validating libnettle6 3.2-1
I: Validating libnewt0.52 0.52.18-1ubuntu2
I: Validating libnih1 1.0.3-4.3ubuntu1
I: Validating libp11-kit0 0.23.2-3
I: Validating libpam-modules 1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2
I: Validating libpam-modules-bin 1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2
I: Validating libpam-runtime 1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2
I: Validating libpam0g 1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2
I: Validating libpcre3 2:8.38-3.1
I: Validating libpng12-0 1.2.54-1ubuntu1
I: Validating libpopt0 1.16-10
I: Validating libprocps4 2:3.3.10-4ubuntu2
I: Validating libpython3-stdlib 3.5.1-3
I: Validating libpython3.5-minimal 3.5.1-10
I: Validating libpython3.5-stdlib 3.5.1-10
I: Validating libreadline6 6.3-8ubuntu2
I: Validating libseccomp2 2.2.3-3ubuntu3
I: Validating libselinux1 2.4-3build2
I: Validating libsemanage-common 2.3-1build3
I: Validating libsemanage1 2.3-1build3
I: Validating libsepol1 2.4-2
I: Validating libslang2 2.3.0-2ubuntu1
I: Validating libsmartcols1 2.27.1-6ubuntu3
I: Validating libsqlite3-0 3.11.0-1ubuntu1
I: Validating libss2 1.42.13-1ubuntu1
I: Validating libssl1.0.0 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4
I: Validating libstdc++6 5.3.1-14ubuntu2
I: Validating libsystemd0 229-4ubuntu4
I: Validating libtasn1-6 4.7-3
I: Validating libtext-charwidth-perl 0.04-7build5
I: Validating libtext-iconv-perl 1.7-5build4
I: Validating libtext-wrapi18n-perl 0.06-7.1
I: Validating libtinfo5 6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1
I: Validating libudev1 229-4ubuntu4
I: Validating libusb-0.1-4 2:0.1.12-28
I: Validating libustr-1.0-1 1.0.4-5
I: Validating libuuid1 2.27.1-6ubuntu3
I: Validating libxtables11 1.6.0-2ubuntu3
I: Validating linux-base 4.0ubuntu1
I: Retrieving locales 2.23-0ubuntu3
I: Validating locales 2.23-0ubuntu3
I: Validating login 1:4.2-3.1ubuntu5
I: Validating logrotate 3.8.7-2ubuntu2
I: Validating lsb-base 9.20160110
I: Validating lsb-release 9.20160110
I: Validating makedev 2.3.1-93ubuntu1
I: Validating mawk 1.3.3-17ubuntu2
I: Validating mime-support 3.59ubuntu1
I: Validating mount 2.27.1-6ubuntu3
I: Validating multiarch-support 2.23-0ubuntu3
I: Validating ncurses-base 6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1
I: Validating ncurses-bin 6.0+20160213-1ubuntu1
I: Validating net-tools 1.60-26ubuntu1
I: Validating netbase 5.3
I: Validating netcat-openbsd 1.105-7ubuntu1
I: Validating passwd 1:4.2-3.1ubuntu5
I: Validating perl-base 5.22.1-9
I: Validating procps 2:3.3.10-4ubuntu2
I: Validating python3 3.5.1-3
I: Validating python3-minimal 3.5.1-3
I: Validating python3.5 3.5.1-10
I: Validating python3.5-minimal 3.5.1-10
I: Validating readline-common 6.3-8ubuntu2
I: Retrieving resolvconf 1.78ubuntu2
I: Validating resolvconf 1.78ubuntu2
I: Validating rsyslog 8.16.0-1ubuntu3
I: Validating sed 4.2.2-7
I: Validating sensible-utils 0.0.9
I: Validating sudo 1.8.16-0ubuntu1
I: Validating systemd 229-4ubuntu4
I: Validating systemd-sysv 229-4ubuntu4
I: Validating sysv-rc 2.88dsf-59.3ubuntu2
I: Validating sysvinit-utils 2.88dsf-59.3ubuntu2
I: Validating tar 1.28-2.1
I: Validating tzdata 2016d-0ubuntu0.16.04
I: Validating ubuntu-keyring 2012.05.19
I: Validating ubuntu-minimal 1.361
I: Validating ucf 3.0036
I: Validating udev 229-4ubuntu4
I: Validating ureadahead 0.100.0-19
I: Validating util-linux 2.27.1-6ubuntu3
I: Validating vim-common 2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1
I: Validating vim-tiny 2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1
I: Validating whiptail 0.52.18-1ubuntu2
I: Validating xkb-data 2.16-1ubuntu1
I: Validating zlib1g 1:1.2.8.dfsg-2ubuntu4
I: Chosen extractor for .deb packages: dpkg-deb
I: Extracting adduser...
I: Extracting base-files...
I: Extracting base-passwd...
I: Extracting bash...
I: Extracting bsdutils...
I: Extracting coreutils...
I: Extracting dash...
I: Extracting debconf...
I: Extracting debianutils...
I: Extracting diffutils...
I: Extracting dpkg...
I: Extracting e2fslibs...
I: Extracting e2fsprogs...
I: Extracting findutils...
I: Extracting gcc-6-base...
I: Extracting grep...
I: Extracting gzip...
I: Extracting hostname...
I: Extracting init...
I: Extracting init-system-helpers...
I: Extracting initscripts...
I: Extracting insserv...
I: Extracting libacl1...
I: Extracting libapparmor1...
I: Extracting libattr1...
I: Extracting libaudit-common...
I: Extracting libaudit1...
I: Extracting libblkid1...
I: Extracting libbz2-1.0...
I: Extracting libc-bin...
I: Extracting libc6...
I: Extracting libcap2...
I: Extracting libcap2-bin...
I: Extracting libcomerr2...
I: Extracting libcryptsetup4...
I: Extracting libdb5.3...
I: Extracting libdebconfclient0...
I: Extracting libdevmapper1.02.1...
I: Extracting libfdisk1...
I: Extracting libgcc1...
I: Extracting libgcrypt20...
I: Extracting libgpg-error0...
I: Extracting libkmod2...
I: Extracting liblzma5...
I: Extracting libmount1...
I: Extracting libncurses5...
I: Extracting libncursesw5...
I: Extracting libpam-modules...
I: Extracting libpam-modules-bin...
I: Extracting libpam-runtime...
I: Extracting libpam0g...
I: Extracting libpcre3...
I: Extracting libprocps4...
I: Extracting libseccomp2...
I: Extracting libselinux1...
I: Extracting libsemanage-common...
I: Extracting libsemanage1...
I: Extracting libsepol1...
I: Extracting libsmartcols1...
I: Extracting libss2...
I: Extracting libsystemd0...
I: Extracting libtinfo5...
I: Extracting libudev1...
I: Extracting libustr-1.0-1...
I: Extracting libuuid1...
I: Extracting locales...
I: Extracting login...
I: Extracting lsb-base...
I: Extracting makedev...
I: Extracting mawk...
I: Extracting mount...
I: Extracting multiarch-support...
I: Extracting ncurses-base...
I: Extracting ncurses-bin...
I: Extracting passwd...
I: Extracting perl-base...
I: Extracting procps...
I: Extracting sed...
I: Extracting sensible-utils...
I: Extracting systemd...
I: Extracting systemd-sysv...
I: Extracting sysv-rc...
I: Extracting sysvinit-utils...
I: Extracting tar...
I: Extracting tzdata...
I: Extracting util-linux...
I: Extracting zlib1g...
```